# RegExp match lines NOT starting with at-symbol

Tags: regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

If I write this regexp `(?<=^[\t ]*@).+` I can match only the lines starting with optional spaces (but not newlines) and at-symbol, without matching the at-symbol.

Example:
`@test` Matches "test", but not the "    @".

I'm trying to match lines that it first not space character is not the at-symbol. For that purpose I negate the look-behind, resulting in this: `(?<!^[\t ]*@).+`.

But it matches lines even if their first non-space character is the at-symbol.

I've tried regexps like these:
`^[\t ]*[^@].*`,
`(?<=^[\t ]*[^@]).+`,
`(?<=^[\t ]*)(.(?!@)).*`.
All of then matches lines even their first non-space character is the at-symbol.

How can I do to match lines not starting with optional spaces (not newlines) and the at-symbol?

```
matches
    matches
m@tches
    m@tches
@Doesn't match
    @Doesn't match
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which language does accept varying length lookbehind (I know none) ?

Comment: Split (read line per line), trim, and check the first character with some `startswith` method. No need using a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern was good except two things:

- you need a lookahead *(followed with)*, not a lookbehind
- you need to anchor your pattern at the start of the line

So, if you read the text line by line:

```
^(?![ \t]*@).+
```

If you read the whole text you need to use the multiline modifier to make `^` to match the start of the line (and not the start of the string by default):

```
(?m)^(?![ \t]*@).+
```

*(or an other way to switch on this m modifier)*